# How to get the name of the originally ran file in Julia

Tags: julia

I'd like to create a log file which is named after the originally run Julia file, for example here `julia foo.jl` I'd want `foo.jl`. From within a Julia session how can I get this information>

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The global constant [`PROGRAM_FILE`](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/constants/#Base.PROGRAM_FILE) is set to the script name.

Answer (score -1):

This can be done by inspecting the stack

```
# first get the top of the stack
f = stacktrace()[1]

# then get the file's name as a string, note the is absolute.
abs_filename = String(f.file)
println(abs_filename)

# to get only the filename use
println(basename(abs_filename))
```